# iOS: Error while building Xcode Project when using Segment-Firebase in pods

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm using segment library via CocoaPods. I have another framework target in the app in which I have added these:

```
target :Model do
    pod 'Segment-Wootric'
    pod 'Segment-Firebase'
end
```

When I try to build the project I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SEGFirebaseIntegration.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SEGFirebaseIntegration.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SEGFirebaseIntegration.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I remove this pod: `pod 'Segment-Firebase'` and do `pod install`
It works fine.

What should I do??

Comment: It seems like both pods are conflicting with one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting any warnings related to linker Flag, I believe I fixed it in past for me by setting up the Linker flag in `Target's Build Settings > Linker Flag property`. Set the value as `$(inherited)`